# Recording FULL HTTP traffic in Apache

Tags: apache, http, logging

I know that Apache can record 'Headers' of HTTP requests. 
Is there any way to configure it so it can record Full HTTP requests and responses (I mean both headers and bodies) similar to what proxy servers do?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like more of a http://serverfault.com/ question, but I think tcpflow might meet your needs: https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow/wiki/tcpflow-%E2%80%94-A-tcp-ip-session-reassembler, or perhaps mod_dumpio: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: ModSecurity (http://modsecurity.org) can also do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob and BazzaDP. I think I will start with trying mod_dumpio. Sorry I should ask it on serverfault (I didn't know about that Web site however.) Thanks